# setTimeout functionality is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the jQuery setTimeout in order to call a method each x time interval:

```
 $('.text').blur(function () {
     doSmth();
 });

 $('.text').bind("paste", function (e) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         doSmth();
     }, 5);
 });
```

The timeout is not working , please advice !

Comment: `setTimeout` is calling the provided function only *once* after the specified delay, as it is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout and as already said, `setTimeout` has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "it's not working"?Anyway setTimeout() is a Javascript function that triggers only once after the specified interval.

If you wan't to trigger something every five second you should do:

```
var interval =  setInterval(doSmth, 5000);
```

Where `doSmth` is a function defined elsewhere and `5000` is the number of millisecond of the interval. If yo want to stop the execution just do:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: From what I've read, it's generally a good idea to avoid setInterval, since you can end up stacking calls. I've added an answer that use setTimeout to call a function, that then sets a new timeout at the end of the function, to call itself again in five seconds. That way you can't end up with a stack of calls.

Answer (score 1):

First, it isn't a *"jQuery setTimeout"*. `setTimeout` is part of the native API, not jQuery's API.

Second, I assume you want *5 seconds*. Currently you're doing *5 milliseconds*.

```
$('.text').bind("paste", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        doSmth();
    }, 5000);
});
```

The duration of `5` in your code is far too short to be perceptible.

Comment: setTimeout execute only once, you should use setInterval

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: Yes, I'm interpreting *"each x time interval"* to mean at the time interval of x each time an event occurs. It isn't entirely clear what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the other answers user setInterval, but from what I've read, you should avoid using setInterval, since you can end up with a stack of not-yet-executed function calls etc.

So what you could do instead is something like this:

```
var myTimeout;  
$('.text').bind("paste", function (e) {
     function loopFunction () {
        doSmth();
        myTimeout = setTimeout(loopFunction, 5000);
     } 
     myTimeout = setTimeout(loopFunction, 5000);
});
```

Now you have a function that calls itself every five seconds.

Comment: I have updated my code according to yours and the method still doesn't call itself !! : $('.sequenceStringArea').blur(function() {
        findMatchedGeneticFeature();
    });

     var myTimeout;  
$('.sequenceStringArea').bind("paste", function (e) {
     function loopFunction () {
        findMatchedGeneticFeature();
        myTimeout = setTimeout(loopFunction, 1000);
     } 
     myTimeout = setTimeout(loopFunction, 1000);
});

Answer (score 0):

According to your feedback,here is the solution:

```
   var interval =  setInterval(doSmth, 5000);


    $('.text').blur(function() {
        doSmth();
    });

    $('.text').bind("paste", function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            doSmth();
        }, 0);
    });
```

Thanks for you amazing support.